# How to save shapefile as type 1 point file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geometry

QGIS saves point shapefiles as type 8 - Multipoint as default. I need QGIS to save as type-1 Point file.

How?

Answer (score 2):

I disagree that QGIS always uses multipoint. If you use the `Extract Nodes` tool, you get a single point layer, and converting `Multipart to singlepart` and back changes the geometry type as expected.

You can run ogrinfo on the shapefiles to check the geometry type.

Unfortunately, QGIS reports the layers metadata always as `Point`.